# How to generate code from a power shell script using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I've a PowerShell script that generates a partial class based on a resource file I've in my cs project.

I'd like to include this new file during compiling time.

Is the [Exec Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) the way to go? And if so, any examples of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by modifying your .csproj file to automatically include files of a particular pattern, e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="GeneratedPartialClasses\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that Visual Studio will also load these files as part of your project, so you may need to be careful that these generated files aren't accidentally checked-in to source control.